# Git authenticated pusher name as author

Tags: git, authentication

Recently I managed to set up git server with Smart HTTP over Apache web server and LDAP authentication. Authentication is held correctly but I also want to make git show LDAP username as a committer (author) instead of name stored on client git repo. How this can be done?

**Step 1.** I commit something

```
git commit -m "Some message"
```

**Step2.** I push it to server

```
git push
//git prompts me for user name and password
Username for http://some.server.com: user1
Password for http://some.server.com: *******
//Pushed successfully
```

**Step 3.** I commit something else

```
git commit -m "Some other message"
```

**Step 4.** I push it to server but as another user - **SomeOtherUser**

```
git push
//git prompts me for user name and password
Username for http://some.server.com: SomeOtherUser
Password for http://some.server.com: **********
//Pushed successfully
```

**Step 5.** Browsing git log

```
git log

Author: git_client_user<git_client_user@mail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 6 12:34:54 2015 +0200

    Some other message

Author: git_client_user<git_client_user@mail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 6 10:59:25 2015 +0200

    Some message
```

However I was authorized as different users git thinks that commit was made by a single person - git_client_user, and I need to distinguish commits even if they were one from single computer but with different credentials.

Comment: So what is the question? Commit user and server authentification are different things. How are you supposed to tell that the pusher is the same person as the committer? These two are configured at different places, the last one has nothing to do with git. In the reverse: what if user has different e-mail and user ID/ whatever in git and on server? You might use the pre-commit hooks to force email / user setting according to what is configured in push or vice-versa, but this is cludging and a bad idea.

Comment: If "author identity theft" is a problem you could use signed commits. But usually, this does not happen in your average development team.

Comment: In the days before git, authentication was a standard feature of VCSes. Then came the DVCSes, and a decision was made that user authentication and source control should not be integrated. Use SSH or HTTP auth, they say. Git does come with a network protocol and server, but it includes no authentication. It seems to me that it might be useful if these distributed VCSes supported also a more classical centralized model of development, including authenticating to a central source control server, but people smarter than me seem convinced that it's good that authentication was thrown out.